# Expresso Store stripe not submitting

Tags: expresso-store, stripe

Weird one, Expresso+Stripe usually works but in this one case it won't!

The payment_token is being generated (after 1-2 second delay) but the form isn't submitting after that.

Jquery is included ok, here's my template (just the important bits, all else is generic stuff)

```
<p>
<select name="payment_method">
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="Stripe">Credit/Debit card</option>
<option value="PayPal_Express">Paypal</option>
</select>
</p>

{!-- STRIPE FORM --}
<input type="text" id="payment_token" name="payment[token]" value="">
<dl>
<dt><label for="s1">Name on card</label></dt>
<dd><input type="text" id="s1" data-stripe="name"></dd>
<dt><label for="s2">Card number</label></dt>
<dd><input type="text" id="s2" data-stripe="number"></dd>
<dt><label for="s3">Expiration month</label></dt>
<dd>
    <select id="s3" data-stripe="exp-month">
    <option value=""></option>
    {exp_month_options}
    </select>
</dd>
<dt><label for="s4">Expiration year</label></dt>
<dd>
    <select id="s4" data-stripe="exp-year">
    <option value=""></option>
    {exp_year_options}
    </select>
</dd>
<dt><label for="s5">CVV</label></dt>
<dd><input type="text" id="s6" size="4" data-stripe="cvc" /></dd>
</dl>

<script>
$(function() {
    $.getScript('https://js.stripe.com/v2/', function() {
        Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_REMOVED');
    });
    /* Ensure your checkout submit button has id="checkout_submit" */
    $checkout_submit = $("#checkout_submit").click(function() {
        /* Only handle requests for Stripe gateway */
        if (this.form.elements["payment_method"].value == "Stripe") {
            /* Temporarily disable the checkout submit button */
            $checkout_submit.attr('disabled', true);
            /* Create a Stripe card token */
            Stripe.card.createToken($(this.form), stripeResponseHandler);
            /* We don't want to submit the form yet */
            return false;
        }
    });
    /* This function is triggered once Stripe has generated the token */
    function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
        /* Re-enable the checkout submit button */
        $checkout_submit.attr('disabled', false);
        /* Check whether we have a valid credit card */
        if (response.error) {
            alert(response.error.message);
        } else {
            /* Set the card token and submit the checkout form */
            $("#payment_token").val(response.id);
            $checkout_submit.off("click").click();
        }
    }
});
</script>


<p class="checkout-next">
    <input type="submit" id="checkout_submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-pri btn-m" value="Place order">
</p>
```

Can't for the life of me see where its failing, no JS errors. Anyone have any idea?s

Comment: Has their been any API updates that break these plugins?

Comment: Try changing `$checkout_submit.off("click").click();` to `$('#form_id').submit();`.

Comment: Also what version of Store are you using along with what version of the Stripe API is your store set to use?

Comment: Derek - good suggestion but that doesn't work, you'd think it should!

Comment: Justin
EE2.9.2
Store 2.5.0
Stripe API is v2

Comment: Update on this one, I've made payment selection a step on the previous page (selection option, paypal or stripe), carries through to payment page. Odd thing it works fine in all browsers except Firefox which requires the submit button to be clicked twice...

Comment: Have you checked your network tab? Are you sure jQuery isn't being loaded twice? That can cause weird conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

I just battled this for half a day myself with Store and Stripe , and the issue ended up being with forms not being able to submit via javascript when there is any element inside the form named `submit`.

This is tricky since originally, Store required that you have an input named `submit` to complete the checkout process. They did add the ability to use `commit` instead though as of version 1.3.

In my testing, naming the submit input - or button - with `commit` still didn't work (it was submitting as an empty value, which Store didn't detect), so I simply added a hidden input instead.

```
<input type="hidden" name="commit" value="y" />
```

Then made sure I left by submission button unnamed:

```
<button type="submit">Submit Payment</button>
```

(One note as well: I opted to use [Stripe's javascript template](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms) - which uses `data-stripe` attributes - as a starting point, as it's much more up-to-date.)

Comment: Cheers Derek. I actually called in DevDemon support in the end who came up with a similar solution!

Comment: I was having the same issue when using the submitHandler in jQuery Validate - https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/#submithandler. Adding the hidden element fixed the problem - thanks. Incidentally, I wasn't using Stripe, it was an onsite PayPal Pro implementation.